# Proof of concept model controller calling correct instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

Here is the code in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adviner/uz49s624/30/)

I have a simple proof of concept code were I have 2 controllers which are the same and a model and model listener.  The controllers are kicked off individually by two different buttons:

require(['jquery',
'Controller1', 'Controller2'], 
function ($, controller1, controller2) 
{
    $(document).ready(function (){

```
    controller1.init();
    controller2.init();

    $('#controller1Click').on('click', function()
    {
        $('#results').val('Controller 1 Click');
        controller1.start();
    });

    $('#controller2Click').on('click', function()
    {
        $('#results').val('Controller 2 Click');
        controller2.start();
    });

});
```

});

When the controllers start() method is called it calls the models retrieveData() method which then executes the notifyLoadBegin() method.  The problem I have is if I click either buttons both controller1 and controller2 loadBegin() method gets called.   In each controller I create a new instance of the model and the listener in each controller so I would assume that the controller would only kick off the instance of the model/listener in that controller.

Here is the controller.  Both controllers are exactly the same except the message that it shows of which controller it is in the loadBegin() method.

```
define('Controller1',
[
'jquery',
'ConfigModel', 'ConfigModelListener'    
], 
function (
    $,
    ConfigModel, ConfigModelListener
) 
{
    var self = {};

    var configModel             = new ConfigModel();
    var configModelListener     = new ConfigModelListener();


    self.init = function()
    {

        var modelListener1 = configModelListener.create({
            loadBegin: function()
            {
               // Controller 1 code
                var buff = $('#results').val();
                $('#results').val(buff + '\r\n' + 'Controller1 loadBegin');
                console.log('Controller1 loadBegin');

               // Controller 2 code (added here so I dont have to duplicate the code
                var buff = $('#results').val();
                $('#results').val(buff + '\r\n' + 'Controller2 loadBegin');
                console.log('Controller2 loadBegin');

            }
        });

        configModel.addListeners(modelListener1);
    }

    self.start = function()
    {
        configModel.retrieveData();
    }

    return self;

});
```

Here is the model and the model listener code:

```
define('ConfigModel', ['jquery'], 
function ($) 
{
    var self = {}; 

    var listeners = [];

    self.retrieveData = function()
    {
        self.notifiyLoadBegin();

    }


    /* Listeners */
    self.addListeners = function(list)
    {
        listeners.push(list);
    }

    self.notifiyLoadBegin = function()
    {
        $.each(listeners, function(i)
        {
            listeners[i].loadBegin();
        });
    }

    return function(){
        return self;
    };


});


define('ConfigModelListener', ['jquery'], 
function ($) 
{
    var self = {}; 

    self.create = function(list)
    {
        if(!list)
            list = {};

        return $.extend({
            loadBegin               : function(){}

        }, list);
    }

    return function(){
        return self;
    };  

});
```

I'm assuming I'm instantiating the model and the model listener incorrectly some how.  Just not sure.

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured it out.  I put my answer in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adviner/1u495whg/2/)
in case anyone is interested or runs into the same issue.  What I did was convert my Model and Model listener to return as a function:

```
define('ConfigModel', ['jquery'], 
function ($) 
{
    function configModel()
    {
        var self = this;
        var listeners = [];

        self.retrieveData = function()
        {
            self.notifiyLoadBegin();
        }
        self.addListeners = function(list)
        {
            listeners.push(list);
        }
        self.notifiyLoadBegin = function()
        {
            $.each(listeners, function(i)
            {
                listeners[i].loadBegin();
            });
        }
    }
    return configModel;
});


define('ConfigModelListener', ['jquery'], 
function ($) 
{
    function configModeListener()
    {
        var self = this;

        self.create = function(list)
        {
            if(!list)
                list = {};

            return $.extend({
                loadBegin : function(){}
            }, list);
        }
    }
    return configModeListener;
});
```

Comment: If possible, it would be great to remove the excess blank lines in your answer, and mark it as accepted so people know the problem has been solved. You should leave the question here, though, so it can help anyone else in the same boat.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add another example in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adviner/nLugsqxo/1/)

This one is more in line with my original sample so I wanted to just added for reference.

The model:

```
function configModel()
{
    var self = {}; 
    var listeners = [];

    self.retrieveData = function()
    {
        self.notifiyLoadBegin();
    }
    // Listeners 
    self.addListeners = function(list)
    {
        listeners.push(list);
    }
    self.notifiyLoadBegin = function()
    {
        $.each(listeners, function(i)
        {
            listeners[i].loadBegin();
        });
    }
    return self;
}
return configModel;
```

The Model Listener:

```
function configModelListener()
{
    var self = {}; 

    self.create = function(list)
    {
        if(!list)
            list = {};
        return $.extend({
            loadBegin               : function(){}

        }, list);
    }       
    return self;
}

return configModelListener;
```